# What happens when we call requestLocationUpdates()?

Tags: android, gps, location-provider

What is the  chain of callbacks when requestLocationupdates() is called? I understand that it calls onLocationChanged but what if the locations is not changed? what if same locations is received? Or it gets called every time a locations is received?

Answer (score 0):

The `requestLocationUpdates()` registers the current activity to be updated periodically by the named provider, or by the provider matching the specified `Criteria`, with location and status updates.

It register for location updates using a Criteria and pending intent

Read [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)